# onSharedPreferenceChanged Invocation for UI Change or Internal

Tags: android

I am using `onSharedPreferenceChanged` to detect changes in a `PreferenceActivity`.

The Key / Value Pair Managed by the `PreferenceActivity` is also changed by code logic.

Default Values also trigger `onSharedPreferenceChanged` function invocation.

Is there a way to distinguish and find out whether user has initiated the change from GUI or the change has been done by code?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot distinguish. The listener will be called irrespective of user initiated or programmatic